# Java - Update variable values within a class

Tags: java, variables

I am trying to update int row and int column based upon user input, but when I run my program, I suspect that it is defaulting to the instantiation values outside the method where I try to update them.  Here is where I delcare them:

```
public class BattleshipGame {

    // Instance variables.
    public static Ocean ocean = new Ocean();
    public int row;
    public int column;
    private int[] shots = new int[2];
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

And then I attempt to update them in this method:

```
int[] acceptShot() {
    System.out.println("\nDrop a bomb at grid (enter row, a space, then    
         column):");
    int[] shots = new int[2];
    shots[0] = scanner.nextInt();
    shots[1] = scanner.nextInt();
    if (shots[0] > 9 || shots[1] > 9) {
        System.out.println("Invalid coordinates.");
        acceptShot();
    }
    System.out.println("You bombed row " + shots[0] + " and column " + shots[1] + ".");
    return shots;
}
```

The ultimate goal is to make them change in this piece of code:

```
void start() {
    setUp();
    ocean.placeAllShipsRandomly();
    ocean.print();
    while (!(ocean.isGameOver())) {
        acceptShot();
        row = shots[0];
        column = shots[1];
        checkForHit(row, column);
    }
    endGame();
}
```

But within the above code, I strongly suspect int row and int column are assigned "null" or something (definitely not integers passed in by the user).

Comment: You probably need to assign the return value from `acceptShot()`, something like `int[] shots = acceptShot();` in the `while` loop in your `start()` method.

Comment: You're the man, thanks! @nickb

Answer (score 0):

This is how it was fixed, thanks @nickb

You probably need to assign the return value from acceptShot(), something like int[] shots = acceptShot(); in the while loop in your start() method. – nickb